# Quantidade de linhas alteradas pelo usuário

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho algumas tabelas em um sistema e para todas as entradas eu faço a validação e comparo se o da entrada é igual ao que estar definido atualmente na tabela e utilizo o PHP rowCount() para verificar se tive atualização e exibo a mensagem correta para o usuário.

Se eu não comparar o valor de entrada com o valor da tabela e executar o update, eu certamente vou exibir uma mensagem de erro para o usuário, uma vez que sendo o valor definido e a nova entrada sendo igual, o SQL não executa o update.

Existe algum parâmetro SQL, ou parametrização, que permita executar o upgrade, mesmo sendo igual o definido atualmente, para que eu evite eternamente esta comparação da entrada com o que está definido atualmente?

Comment: Ocorre algum erro ao tentar atualizar um registro com o mesmo valor que já está em banco?

Comment: Não gera nenhuma falha quando faço o upgrade com os dados iguais ao do banco de dados, só que eu costumo verificar com rowCount() se teve atualização no banco, o retorno é 0(zero). Com o script atual posso exibir uma mensagem de erro. Um outro detalhe, utilizo Exception (try / catch), posso desconsiderar o rowCount() e usar o try catch considerando que tive êxito. O que acha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `mysqli_affected_rows` que retorna  a quantidade de linhas que foram alteradas.

**Tabela**:

```
+----+----------+--------------------+
| id | nome     | email              |
+----+----------+--------------------+
|  1 | Laerte   | laerte@gmail.com   |
|  2 | Ana      | ana@gmail.com      |
+----+----------+--------------------+
```

**Script**:

```
<?php
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

    if (!$conexao) {
        printf("Não foi possível conectar ao banco. Erro: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    /* UPDATE com valores iguais */
    mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE contatos SET nome = 'Laerte', email = 'laerte@gmail.com' WHERE id = 1");
    printf("# de linhas alteradas: %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($conexao));

    /* UPDATE com um valor igual e outro diferente. */
    mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE contatos SET nome = 'Laerte', email = 'laerte.stack@gmail.com' WHERE id = 1");
    printf("<br># de linhas alteradas: %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($conexao));

    mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

**Saída**:

```
# de linhas alteradas: 0
# de linhas alteradas: 1
```

Essa função retorna as **Rows Changed**, como pode ser visto na saída do console:

> mysql> UPDATE contatos SET nome = 'Laerte', email = 'laerte@gmail.com'
>   WHERE id = 1; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec) Rows matched: 1 
>   Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
>
> mysql> UPDATE contatos SET nome = 'Laerte', email =
>   'laerte.stack@gmail.com' WHERE id = 1;  Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04
>   sec) Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

Referência: [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.affected-rows.php)